# How do I draw a area plot in ggplot with timeseries data?

Tags: python, pandas, ggplot2

I'm trying to post a graph like [this](http://chrisalbon.com/python/ggplot_area_plot.html).

My data set looks like this. It has two columns. The first is the date and the second is the total number:

```
date    volume

3/21/16 280

3/20/16 279

3/18/16 278

3/4/16  277
```

I am at a loss on how to make the graph from the link work with my data set. Thank you so much.

```
# Import required modules
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import ggplot

 # Data
data = pd.read_csv("niagra-falls-escape.csv") # Read CSV
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Viz
ggplot(df, aes(x='date')) + \
geom_area()</code>
```

Comment: Looks like you are not importing the ggplot module. Does it work if you add an `from ggplot import *` to the top of your script?

Comment: @cr1msonB1ade Thanks for responding! OK I imported ggplot. Now I'm getting the error: **NameError: name 'aes' is not defined**

Comment: Did you import it as suggested or did you use `import ggplot`?

Comment: I used import ggplot

Comment: Here is the file if you need it:  [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/40gltw52bbchyd4/niagra-falls-escape.csv?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple issues here. First `aes`, `geom_area` etc, are classes of the `ggplot` module. Thus as in the referenced post they import via `from ggplot import *` instead of `import ggplot`. What I would recommend for easier debugging and maintainable code is to do `from ggplot import ggplot, aes, geom_area`.

Then there are a couple issues with your code. I think you need to specify that the date is a datetime type of data. you can do this by adding a line `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`.

Then you will also need to specify the y axis (both ymin and ymax for an area plot) of your plot. This can be done by: `ggplot(df, aes(x='date', ymin='0', ymax='volume')) + geom_area()`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Still getting an error. It says "AttributeError: 'EvalEnvironment' object has no attribute 'add_outer_namespace'.

Comment: Yeah I get that error too. Seems to be an issue with the new version of pandas interacting with the ggplot package. Here is the SO exchange for that: https://github.com/yhat/ggplot/issues/457 Looks like there is a fork with a fix, but the master package is apparently broken at the moment.

Comment: Well I'm not 100% married to ggplot. Any suggestions on how to get this done with another library?

Comment: matplotlib is probably the best maintained package. python's plotting package repertoire is not that great IMHO though.